# docker build failed when i try configure rabbitmq

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I've tried to configure exchanges, queues and bindings in rabbitmq

My Dockerfile :

```
FROM rabbitmq:3-management
RUN apt update
RUN apt install wget zip -y
RUN wget https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq/community-plugins/3.7.x/rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange/rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange-20171201-3.7.x.zip
RUN unzip rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange-20171201-3.7.x.zip -d /plugins
RUN ls /plugins
RUN export RABBITMQ_PLUGINS_DIR=/plugins
RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable --offline rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange
COPY definitions.json /definitions.json
```

Error :

> File "/usr/local/bin/rabbitmqadmin", line 542, in http
>   except ConnectionRefusedError as e:
>   NameError: global name 'ConnectionRefusedError' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I forgot to specify vhost.